# Parsing annotations within comments / Negative matching of strings in regexps

Tags: kframework

I'm defining the syntax of the [Move IR](https://github.com/diem/diem/tree/main/language). The test suite for this language includes various annotations to enable testing. I need to treat comments of this form specially:

```
//! new-transaction
// check: "Keep(ABORTED { code: 123,"
```

This file is an example [arithmetic_operators_u8.mvir](https://github.com/diem/diem/blob/main/language/ir-testsuite/tests/move/operators/arithmetic_operators_u8.mvir).

So far, I've got this working by disallowing ordinary single-line comments.

```
module MOVE-ANNOTATION-SYNTAX-CONCRETE
    imports INT-SYNTAX
    syntax #Layout ::= r"([\\ \\n\\r\\t])"       // Whitespace                                                          
    syntax Annotation ::= "//!" "new-transaction" [klabel(NewTransaction), symbol]                                      
    syntax Check ::= "//" "check:" "\"Keep(ABORTED { code:" Int ",\"" [klabel(CheckCode), symbol]                                                                                                                                         
endmodule                                                                                                               
                                                                                                                  
module MOVE-ANNOTATION-SYNTAX-ABSTRACT
    imports INT-SYNTAX
    syntax Annotation ::= "#NewTransaction" [klabel(NewTransaction), symbol]                                            
    syntax Check ::= #CheckCode(Int)        [klabel(CheckCode), symbol]                                                 
endmodule
```

I'd like to also be able to use ordinary comments.
As a first step, I was able to change the Layout to allow commits only if the begin with a `!` using `r"(\\/\\/[^!][^\\n\\r]*)"`

I'd like to exclude all comments that start with either `//!` or `// check:` from comments. What's a good way of implementing this?
Where can I find documentation for the regular expression language that K uses?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

K uses flex for its scanner, and thus for its regular expression language. As a result, you can find documentation on its regular expression language [here](https://westes.github.io/flex/manual/Patterns.html#Patterns).

You want a regular expression that expresses that comments can't start with `!` or `check:`, but flex doesn't support negative lookahead or not patterns, so you will have to exhaustively enumerate all the cases of comments that don't start with those sequence of characters. It's a bit tedious, sadly.

For reference, here is a (simplified) regular expression drawn from the syntax of C that represents all pragmas that don't start with `STDC`. It should give you an idea of how to proceed:

```
#pragma([:space:]*)([^S].*|S|S[^T].*|ST|ST[^D].*|STD|STD[^C].*|STDC[_a-zA-Z0-9].*)?$
```